# Running a Script to automount servers on a network OSx

Tags: macos

So, I have a a server that is 100G at my house, that everyone saves stuff to. I have a new server that is 1 TB, and want people to start saving to this server because it's bigger. Everyone in my house uses a macbook, so is it possible to write a script to have people automatically mount to this new server instead of manually connecting to it? I know it can be done manually, but writing a script seems like a reusable tool and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
 myName to do shell script "whoami"
try
    mount volume "smb://server/"
end try
```